# Unable to handle Windows 10 pop-ups using Robot class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, awtrobot

I am trying to run the below code in Internet Explorer, Windows 10.

----------------------------Test---------------public class SampleTest {

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws AWTException, InterruptedException{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "path//IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.get("url");
    HelperMethods.validateSplash();
}
```

}`
--------------------HelperMethods-----------

`
public class HelperMethods {

```
public static void validateSplash() throws AWTException, InterruptedException{
    HelperMethods.ctrlV("username");
    HelperMethods.pressTab();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    HelperMethods.ctrlV("password");
    HelperMethods.pressEnter();
}

private static void ctrlV(String stringToPaste) throws AWTException{
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    StringSelection strToPaste = new StringSelection(stringToPaste);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(strToPaste, null);            
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
}

private static void pressTab() throws AWTException{
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
}

private static void pressEnter() throws AWTException{
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
}
```

}`

When I try to run the above script in Windows 7(Desktop), it is working fine. But when I try to run the same in Windows 10(laptop), it is not working.

Can someone please help. Thanks

Comment: What exactly happens when you run it in Win 10? Are there any error messages?

Comment: This is exactly why hacking a solution together with Robot classes is generally a bad idea, it's not really cross platform.  What is the real problem you are trying to solve? Is it to enter basic auth credentials to get access to a website you want to test?  If so there are better ways to do it.

Comment: @Ardesco - Yes, I am trying to validate Windows Authentication pop-up here. Could you please suggest any alternative.

Comment: @MateMrše - I am not getting any error, but the Robot class is not sending the credentials to the pop-up. It keeps on loading, and finally the test is getting failed with timeout exception.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a hack like Java Robot classes for Basic Auth, what you really want to do is use a proxy.  Here's a solution using the [browserup proxy](https://github.com/browserup/browserup-proxy).

First of all add the browserup proxy dependency to your maven POM.xml (this is assuming you are using maven, it's pretty standard with Java projects though).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.browserup</groupId>
    <artifactId>browserup-proxy-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then use the browserup proxy in your tests.  First of all the imports you are going to need to run this are as follows:

```
import com.browserup.bup.BrowserUpProxy;
import com.browserup.bup.BrowserUpProxyServer;
import com.browserup.bup.client.ClientUtil;
import com.browserup.bup.proxy.auth.AuthType;
import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerOptions;
```

Then an example test that you should be able to copy/paste and try out is:

```
// Start up the browserup proxy server
BrowserUpProxy browserUpProxyServer = new BrowserUpProxyServer();
//Specify domain that uses basic auth, then the username and password followed by auth type
browserUpProxyServer.autoAuthorization("the-internet.herokuapp.com", "admin", "admin", AuthType.BASIC);
browserUpProxyServer.start();
Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(browserUpProxyServer);

// Configure IEDriver to use the browserup proxy
InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
ieOptions.setProxy(seleniumProxy);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);

//Go to a site with basic auth enabled and check it all works
driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth");

//Clean up after test has finished
driver.quit();
browserUpProxyServer.stop();
```

It should be a relatively simple job to tweak the autoAuthorization line to make it work for your domain and your associated basic auth credentials.

The advantages to using a proxy are:

- This is cross browser compliant
- This is cross OS compliant
- This will work with local and remote WebDriver instances (However with remote ones the machine that the browser is running on will need access to the machine that the proxy is running on and you need to pass in a valid IP address for the proxy, not localhost)
- It's a lot less code than various Robot class hacks to try and and click on varying different OS level dialogue boxes.

Comment: this works best for basic auth, but when used for NTLM `AuthType.NTLM`, it throws - `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: AuthType NTLM is not supported for HTTP Authorization`. Is there any different way of handling NTLM? Please help.

Comment: You would need to understand what NTLM is transmitting to the server (is is a header with some sort of auth key?). I would suggest having a look at the network traffic using a proxy like Charles to see what is sent over when you have performed an NTLM auth.  Another option would be something like this : http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net